# How to split by dot?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

How can I split a string by different symbols including dots?

```
currency_title = "USD.RUB.EUR"
currency_arr = re.split('&|,|/|and|.',currency_title)
```

I get many empty substrings why?
Please notice that I want to use regex `re`, not split.

Comment: `r'&|,|/|and|.'` -> `r'&|,|/|and|\.'` -> `r'[&,/.]|and'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Which of the last two options is correct?

Comment: `r'&|,|/|and|\.'` (fixed) -> `r'[&,/.]|and'` (enhanced)